# Drupal and node.js configuration

Tags: rules, notifications

I have a problem with *Nodejs* and *Rules action with node.js* modules

First, I have installed node.js on my server following the README.txt instructions and then configured the node.config.js file as the sample file and had no problem connecting Drupal with node.js. But after creating a rule of new nodes, I checked messages like this in the debugger:

```
Started http server.
   info  - socket.io started
publishMessageToContentChannel: message { uniqid: '520d016b52adc',
  markup: '<div class="rules-message">\n  <div class="close-button"></div>\n    
<div class="body">\n    <div class="subject">\n      TEST TITLE    </div>\n    
value of body action message  </div>\n</div>\n',
  callback: 'nodejsAction',
  messageAuthorUid: '1',
  channel: 'rules_nodejs_role_2',
  clientSocketId: '' }
publishMessageToContentChannel: message { uniqid: '520d016b52adc',
  markup: '<div class="rules-message">\n  <div class="close-button"></div>\n    
<div class="body">\n    <div class="subject">\n      TEST TITLE    </div>\n
value of body action message  </div>\n</div>\n',
  callback: 'nodejsAction',
  messageAuthorUid: '1',
  channel: 'rules_nodejs_user_3',
  clientSocketId: '' }
publishMessageToContentChannel: The channel "rules_nodejs_user_3" doesn't exist.
publishMessageToContentChannel: message { channel: 'watchdog_dblog',
  commands:
   [ { command: 'insert',
       method: 'before',
       selector: '#admin-dblog tr:eq(1)',
       data: '<tr class="dblog-content dblog-notice"><td class="icon"></td><td>content</td><td>08/15/2013 - 12:27</td>
          <td>page: added <em class="placeholder">node 18</em>.</td><td><a href="/user/1" title="View user profile." class="username" 
          xml:lang="" about="/user/1" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name" datatype="">admin</a></td><td><a 
          href="/node/18">view</a></td></tr>',
       settings: null } ],
  callback: 'nodejsWatchdog',
  clientSocketId: '' }
publishMessageToContentChannel: The channel "watchdog_dblog" doesn't exist.
setContentToken: message { token: 'Xx0RmC36fXFTnyH_goIX21fP-2iDJMhTk_u-iWBpcM4',
  channel: 'rules_nodejs_user_1',
  notifyOnDisconnect: false }
setContentToken Xx0RmC36fXFTnyH_goIX21fP-2iDJMhTk_u-iWBpcM4 for channel rules_nodejs_user_1
setContentToken: message { token: 'u3EbOVHjEdIiL6mlGbN8p4T5CifL2Gt-tZc2jfqfbCE',
  channel: 'rules_nodejs_role_2',
  notifyOnDisconnect: false }
setContentToken u3EbOVHjEdIiL6mlGbN8p4T5CifL2Gt-tZc2jfqfbCE for channel rules_nodejs_role_2
setContentToken: message { token: '9WLPPJWOr7XlMXLYbhhiuBvMwN4Bd4o9_6exS-_cspU',
  channel: 'rules_nodejs_role_3',
  notifyOnDisconnect: false }
setContentToken 9WLPPJWOr7XlMXLYbhhiuBvMwN4Bd4o9_6exS-_cspU for channel rules_nodejs_role_3
```

However, I couldn't get the notifications on my browser and I don't know if I'm missing some extra configuration for it.

Answer (score 0):

[noddejs](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs) module is hard to configure and make it work as it is under development and not stable yet (I tried personally)

take a look at tha sandbox project it may help [nodejs-chat-d7](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mhmd/2508219)

Comment: This question was asked in 2013, and the asker was last seen in Oct 22 '13.

Comment: The answer if for searchers not only the asker, We must search before ask new questions